# How to modify the max size of a tablespace oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table space called ts witch has a maximum size 10go I need to add a 1go how can I proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about the automatic extension of data files?

In that case the command you need will be similar to this:

```
alter database datafile 'filename' autoextend on next 512K maxsize 11G;
```

See the section [Enabling and Disabling Automatic Extension for a Data File](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/dfiles.htm#ADMIN11424) of the Oracle 12.1 Database Administrator's Guide.

Comment: I used this command but I keep get something like you can't reach maxsize

Comment: What's the exact command you ran and the Oracle error message you got?

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3002.htm

I guess this only makes sense if you have autoextend enabled?  If you do then you can pick out the syntax from the documentation, something like this?

```
ALTER TABLESPACE myTableSpace RESIZE 11G
```